# Is there a specific name for experiencing vertigo on sloping floors?

Tags: nausea, vertigo, equilibrium-balance

I wasn't sure where to ask this or what tags to use, but this seemed like the right place. Is there a specific name for experiencing vertigo-like symptoms when on sloping/tilted floors, almost like being seasick? Or is it just called vertigo?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?